# User folder accidently relocated, don't have permissions to move it back (Read only file system)

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04

Thanks to a rashly typed `mv` command and my inexperience in installing LaTeX packages, I managed to move my user folder--let's call it `/home/bob` for the purposed of not revealing my name--somewhere else. I started a recovery terminal and found `bob` buried down in `usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex`.

I tried moving the folder back (going to `usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex` and running `mv bob /home/`, but I got the message

`mv: cannot move 'bob' to '/home/bob': Read-only file system`

I don't really know what else to do to fix this... Do I just use `chmod` and change the permissions or do I have to remount something? Since these are *all* my files, I'd rather ask and be sure than play around more and just make things worse.

EDIT: I tried `chmod 777 bob` but got the message

`chmod: changing permissions of 'bob': Read-only file system`

Also, `mkdir /home/bob` gave me a similar error (Read-only file system)

Comment: You're in single user mode, which has mounted the file systems as read-only. You need to remount the file system as read/write in order to move the directory back. Do, as root, `mount -o remount,rw /` to remount the root file system as read-write and then do `mv bob /home/`; if this still doesn't work e.g if `/home` is a different partition and not mounted read-write, then repeat the remount command for `/home` using `mount -o remount,rw /home`, and then retry the mv.

Answer (score 0):

Use `chmod`

```
chmod 777 bob

mv bob/ /home
```

or You can create a folder with similar name

```
mkdir /home/bob
```

Comment: use `sudo` or become root

Comment: I am root! This is recovery mode. My terminal prompt is called `root@COMPUTER-NAME`

Comment: Ok sorry I have taken your time for nothing fruitful outcome, @Thornshadow17432

Comment: no problem bro we're here for help, I would check again if I get anything useful for your problem's solution.